# React Native Press Two Buttons at the same time

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

**Goal**

I need users to be able to press up to 4 buttons at the same time in React Native.

**Current Roadblock**

I'm using TouchableHighlight and when one button is pressed, none of the other 3 buttons can be pressed by the user.

**Code**

This is the function I'm using to display each of the 4 coloured quadrants you see below.  If including more code will be helpful, just let me know!

```
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[styles.button, styles[color]]}
        onPress={() => {
          EventRegister.emit('firstPressed', color);
          EventRegister.removeEventListener(this.listener);
          this.setState({[color]: true});
        }}
        disabled={this.state[color]}></TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };
```

**Screenshot**

This is a screenshot of the app where once the countdown clock gets to zero, 4 players race to push each button as quickly as they can (it's an iPad app so they have a large playing surface).  Each player needs to receive feedback from their touch or they will think they lost because the app didn't recognize their input.

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: You'll have to use high level touch events handling, the Touchable components provided are designed to prevent the behaviour you are looking for. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system

Comment: Thanks @FMCorz !  That was really helpful!  I started using the gesture responder system and it's working!  I need to be able to disable each button after its been pressed once though, do you know how to do this?  I can't figure it out from the documentation

Comment: @bzlight were you able to get touching two at the same time working? Can't figure out how to use the gesture responder to do it.